# Translating old-style expressions like "log. cos." or "arith. comp. of log. cos." to modern notation

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Wondering if there is a way to translate some old-style trigonometric calculations that used tables and notation like `log. cos.` or `arith. comp. of log. cos.` to something that can be done on a **computer, and without tables**?

To put it simpler, does anybody know an algorithm to calculate:

- `log.cos. θ`
- `arith. comp. of log. cos. θ`

as in this screenshot

[image]

taken from the book [Plane Trigonometry and Mensuration, for the use of the Royal Military College](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=LY69wbfzvD4C&lpg=PA103&ots=CDKgJhoACJ&dq=log-cos%20arith.%20comp.&pg=PA99#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Are you really interested in translating these logarithmic computations into modern form? Or do you simply want to solve for the given parts of the triangle with contemporary techniques? All this example is doing is applying the Law of Sines; for instance, in the first part solves for $b$ in $$\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B} \quad\to\quad b = \frac{a \sin B}{\sin A}$$ A computer would evaluate the right-hand side easily; translation to logarithmic form is unnecessary.

Comment: @Blue The question is mostly from the curiosity standpoint as I could not find any good concise explanation of what they actually meant in those old books. Hopefully next curious person will now have a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base 10 logarithms in the old days were expressed as $-10$ to avoid negative numbers, and it made calculations from tables easier.  $\log \sin 49°23'$ is represented as $9.880289$, but it really meant $9.880289-10$ (the actual value is $-0.1191711$).

The "arith. comp." (arithmetic complement) is also known as the cologarithm ("colog"), and  is the reciprocal of the log function $\left (\log \dfrac {1} {x} = -\log x\right)$.

If you wanted to do it on a computer, you could define functions as follows...

$\text {function (OldLogSin(x))} := \log(\sin(x))+10$

$\text {function (OldLogCos(x))} := \log(\cos(x))+10$

$\text {function (Colog(x))} := -\log(x)$

If your computer uses natural (base $e$) logarithms, use $\dfrac {\ln x}{\ln 10}$ to get a base $10$ logarithm; if your computer uses radians, multiply $x$ by the factor $\dfrac {180}{\pi}$ to get degrees.

$\text {function (OldLogSin(x))} := \dfrac {\left[\ln\left(\sin \dfrac {180 \cdot x}{\pi}\right)\right]}{\ln 10}+10$

$\text {function (OldLogCos(x))} := \dfrac {\left[\ln\left(\cos \dfrac {180 \cdot x}{\pi}\right)\right]}{\ln 10}+10$

Comment: That's an excellent explanation, thank you so much! I have run some computer calculations to test the formulae and made it eventually work. Although, `colog` should actually be `log(1/x) = -log(x)`, right?
In my experiments `arith.comp.of log.sin` numerically matches `(10 - OldLogSin(x))`.
And lastly, to get an angle value back from its log.sin I used:
`let d = pow(10, v - 10); return acos(d) * 180 / .pi`

Comment: You're welcome!  Yes, $\log \frac {1}{x} = -\log x$, thus I've corrected my original post to reflect that.